# Hi there, I'm a newbie to ubuntu and just installed ubuntu 20.04 and after the install I noticed that my wifi driver was unrecognized

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom

I was using windows 7 before the update and before the update the driver was working good it was detecting all the WiFi networks but after the update there is a notification which is 'NO WIFI - ADAPTER FOUND'. My WIFI driver model is -07:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)

Please help me, I have to attend my classes, so please help me as soon.

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the title of your question to just reflect the question. This site is aimed to gather knowledge in a format useable in the future, so question should be properly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install the Broadcom STA driver for this device. So long as you have a wired network connection, you can do it like this:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Update Apt:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
2. Remove the current wireless driver (if it's installed):

   ```
   sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
   ```
3. Install the Broadcom STA drivers:

   ```
   sudo apt install broadcom-sta-source broadcom-sta-dkms broadcom-sta-common
   ```
4. Reboot

This should allow you to use the wireless device.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!...This helped me..Thank you once again!

Comment: @AkshithThota You can acccept the answer (by clicking on the check mark), since it worked for you.